# "I have more bikes and cars than him"

Tags: comparatives

> I have more bikes and cars than him.
>
> Gotham has more traffic lights and large roads than Paris.

Are these right or wrong?

Note: I didn't compare the size of their roads. I compared the number of their large roads.

Answer (score 5):

The first sentence is wrong as far as formal writing is concerned. The correct form is:

**I have more bikes and cars than he (has).** Adding **has** is optional. However, the example sentence you gave is more common in informal writing and speaking.

The second sentence is correct.

Comment: I always understood that "than he has" is only correct if "have"/"has" is used as an auxiliary verb, that in this case it should be "I have more bikes and cars than he (does)", but it would be "I have seen more bikes and cars than he (has)". Are you sure it should be "(has)" in this case? (I'm having trouble finding an answer either way.)

Comment: You are right @hvd We can use "does" as well, but the usage of "has" is not incorrect. I am also finding it difficult to know about the usage of "has vs. does" in the scenario given above.

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence only makes sense if "him" refers to either a bike or a car in your possession.  Like ["Herbie"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbie) or ["KITT"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_Rider_%281982_TV_series%29) or some other vehicle that you attribute with enough personality to refer to it with a gender.  Otherwise you really need to write "he" to indicate you are comparing owners here rather than possessions.

The second is fine since the nominative case of "Paris" does not look any different than the accusative case.